# How to get all value by their main user_name where username are related

Tags: mysql

I m in pblem of getting values from this database. i need total request_amount sorted by sim_id where username are related to each other by user_name and parents. For example `Alam=>Shimul`, `Shimul=>Shihab`, `Shihab=>Khaled` and so on... Then when i search only by `user_name='Alam'` which are the main parents of all `user_name` then the output will be following....

Data table `user_request`

```
user_name   sim_id  request_amount  request_date  parents
Alam        1        98             2014-01-11    Admin
Shimul      2       100             2014-01-11    Alam
Shihab      3        50             2014-01-11    Shimul
Khaled      2        20             2014-01-11    Shihab
Sumon       3       100             2014-01-11    Shihab
```

Ouput will be

```
user_name    sim_id1        sim_id2         sim_id3        total
Alam          98              0               0              98
Shimul         0            100               0             100
Shihab         0              0              50             200
Khaled         0             20               0              20
Sumon          0              0             100             100
```

Please somebody help me to fix the pblem.....

Comment: Where does `Shihab` total = `200` come from?

Comment: See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Shihab total = 200. Ops that was a mistake and sorry for that... Thank you for suggest me & i think your link will be helpful for me...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using SUM but with an IF inside the SUM:-

```
SELECT user_name, 
        SUM(IF(sim_id = 1, request_amount, 0)) AS sim_id1,
        SUM(IF(sim_id = 2, request_amount, 0)) AS sim_id2,
        SUM(IF(sim_id = 3, request_amount, 0)) AS sim_id3,
        SUM(sim_id) AS total
FROM user_request
GROUP BY user_name
```

Comment: This query retrieve all data from the table, but i have to search by a user_name then the query retrieve data from table related to the user_name hierarchically ...

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you update your question with a few more examples showing what this query returns and what you want it to return?

Comment: Please see the user_name and parents which are related hierarchically to each other. Then if i search by a user_name='Alam'(for example) it will return the data where Alam=>Shimul, Shimul=>Shihab, Shihab=>Khaled following the given output above

Comment: Not really possible in pure SQL. MySQL does not support recursive queries, although you can fudge it a bit using a recursive stored procedure. To do this in pure SQL without writing a stored procedure would probably require redesigning your table to use the nested set model.